# Setting user_data in session giving different results

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Ok, so this one perplexes me.

When the user logs in I set the userdata in the session like so:

```
$data = array();
$data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
// get the user's info where it matches their email in the db. 
$user = $this->User_model->get_user($data);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_session', $user);
```

Now this works great. It creates `user_session` in the session data as an object. Which I'm ok with.

Then when the user updates their information, I want to reset the data in the `user_session` to match their new data. I do this like so:

```
$data = array(
    'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
    'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
    'street1' => $this->input->post('street1'),
    'street2' => $this->input->post('street2'),
    'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
    'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
    'zip' => $this->input->post('zip'),
    'password' => $encrypted_password,
    'organizations_id' => $this->input->post('org_select')
 );

$user = $this->User_model->get_user($data);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_session', $data);
```

Now the `$data` here is being used to update their information in the DB and then I reuse it to pull their data out via indexing at their `email`.

Lastly, here is the model method I use for both of them:

```
public function get_user($data)
{
  return $this->db
      ->where('email', $data['email'])
      ->select('first_name, last_name, email, password, id, organizations_id')
      ->get('users')
      ->row();
}
```

This works but differently. Instead of giving me an object, it just gives me an array. Which causes a whole hell of a lot of problems elsewhere in my code.

How do I control wether or not it gives me an object or an array?

---

EDIT:

I realized an idiot move. I was sending `$data` instead of `$user` to my model when the user changed their information.

So I fixed the problem and now I get an object both times. But I still want to know how the two methods gave different results. That way I can control it in the future.

So with that being said, here is my OFFICIAL QUESTION:

How do I control the input of session data so that it is either an array or an object?

Answer (score 0):

well the best option - make a field called uniqueid in your users table. when you create the user - generate a random string - that is your unique id - include it in the insert data.

create a new session - store only the unique id .

then when you update the Users table - the unique id in the session stays the same. you return the updated result to your controller and you don't have to fuss with the session.

a typical process after unique id is set:

- get the unique id from session
- search users table with unique id
- users table returns an object (or array) containing the fields you need
- use that user object in your app (not the session)

so **we are only using the session cookie to store the unique id**. and now we have options - if the user is submitting a form to update their profile then you can pass the unique id in a hidden form field. you get the unique id and you dont have to deal with cookies. again that is only for appropriate for scrambled unique id strings (not sequential ids).

**edit:** if you use a sequential id then suddenly you have opened up a security hole. it might not matter for this particular app, but i am recommending this approach because its so versatile.

another way to do this - especially if you have more complicated app where users are doing things and drawing from different tables. say if you need to accumulate or track what a user does through the session - you can have a table that oversees the session - and you use the unique id. then store the 'user' id - the sequential one - in the session table. you can then add more ids for other tables, date time, status, errors, totals, whatever -- for that session.

so then with the unique id - you get back an object say called $editsession with easy to get at values like $editsession->userid $editsession->storyid $editsession->status

```
// example get your user 
 if( ! $user = $this->user->_get($editsession->userid) ; )  
 {  $this->_error() ;  }  
 else { $this->_showEditor($user) ;}
```

and this is a sample random string generator

```
 $uniqueid =  random_string( 'alnum', 10 );
```

finally note that i call the model just 'user' . even a month ago i would have added '_model' or '_m' to the model file name. **but that is wrong - it just adds noise** - so just get out of the habit now and your code will be much cleaner. all the files are clearly in a folder called models :-)

Comment: Thats actually a really good idea. Does it have to be a random string? or can I just use an auto incremented number in the db (thats how it is set up at the moment anyway. each user has their own unique number, but its not random)